# Integrating Intel fortran compiler with XCode IDE

Tags: xcode, macos, intel-fortran, xcode11.3.1

I want to integrate Intel HPC Toolkit to XCode IDE but the path is not provided automatically. Which path should I choose? [image: screenshot]
I have to use XCode 11.3.1 because I cannot update the software system (It is Mojave now). I tried `~/install.sh` and I got 'There is no Contents directory in XCode' error
[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue. In case someone needs it: I moved XCode app from downloads folder to apps folder.